# ServiceStack deserializing Get request when not scalar

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

Say I have an Order object, with a unique OrderNo (effectively an id). It looks like this:

```
[Route("/orders/{OrderNo}", "GET")]
class Order
{
    OrderNo OrderNo;
}

class OrderNo
{ 
  ulong Value {get;set;}
}
```

Now with a regular GET request like so:

```
www.myservice.com/orders/123
```

I get a deserialization error because OrderNo property of Order is not scalar.
I'm wondering how I would be able to customize the deserialization to accomodate for the extra layer.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty obvious what the problem is, you can't match on Object graphs in the Route mappings. Make OrderNo a scalar variable (e.g. int, long, etc).